# Ruby on Rails - Why dont nested transactions that "raise ActiveRecord::Rollback" roll back?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I would expect `a` and `b` to be nil since the `raise` in the inner transaction will “bubble up” to the outer transaction, but thats not the case. `a` and `b` still have values. Why is this happening?

```
a = nil
b = nil
Foo.transaction do
  a = Bar.create! name: 'a'
  Foo.transaction do
    b = Bar.create! name: 'b'
    raise ActiveRecord::Rollback
  end
end

puts "a: #{a.reload.inspect}" #has value
puts "b: #{b.reload.inspect}" #has value
```

Comment: Here is a [detailed blog post](https://pragtob.wordpress.com/2017/12/12/surprises-with-nested-transactions-rollbacks-and-activerecord/) explaining why this happens. Nested transactions are tricky.

Comment: Some other details [here](https://makandracards.com/makandra/42885-nested-activerecord-transaction-pitfalls) and [here](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Transactions/ClassMethods.html#module-ActiveRecord::Transactions::ClassMethods-label-Nested+transactions). You can use `joinable` and `requires_new` for additional control but some of it is database dependent for actual nested transactions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I gather from [the ROR docs](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Transactions/ClassMethods.html#module-ActiveRecord::Transactions::ClassMethods-label-Nested+transactions) and [this post](https://pragtob.wordpress.com/2017/12/12/surprises-with-nested-transactions-rollbacks-and-activerecord/) the inner transaction rolls back, but the outer transaction still commits the inner one therefore all the objects get persisted despite the `raise`.